# How can check If Windows 10 Is Genuine or Not?

Tags: windows, windows-genuine-advantage

So many articles in the web tell how to check the window's genuine or not,most of them use command `slmgr  /dlv`:

[image]

This is truly a not genuine version,if enabled with activation code,how can check then?

Comment: It says "Licence Status: Notification" rather than "Licenced"

Comment: @John I see this error: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-activation-error-0xc004f034/ea377818-f721-4bf3-98df-6effbfec6530

Comment: Your license key, 2B87N-8KFHP-DKV6R-Y2C8J-PKCKT, is a generic license key and cannot be used to activate Windows. You need to change the license key to an actual Retail Windows 10 N Pro license key

Answer (score 1):

You can see it on the main Settings page, at the bottom - marked here in red

[image]

Search in here for Activation for more detail…

[image]

*Images from a VM which I never bother activating.*

Alternatively, from your command `slmgr  /dlv` it's in the License Status line - Notification means not activated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> This is truly a not genuine version,if enabled with activation code,how can check then?

The fact you cannot activate the key suggests you have a generic Windows 10 Pro N key associated with the installation. You will need to change the key, using the appropriate command, to activate your installation.

Just by the last 5 characters of the key, it’s 2B87N-8KFHP-DKV6R-Y2C8J-PKCKT, which is listed on the Microsoft website as a generic key. Generic keys are only valid and useful to simply install Windows.

If it was a genuine Windows installation license key your installation would already be activated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-client-activation-keys

In this case the generic key for Windows 10 N Professional has changed, but nonetheless, that key at one time was the official generic key.

https://windowsloop.com/windows-10-generic-activation-keys/